# Parsing json array And Merging Objects via php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I Have a json array with `id` `type` `answer` I'm merging `id`, `type` and `answer` together and put them in the `id2` column, so why can't I get $answers value in output?

```
[{"id":"38","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"HIGH"}],"type":"a"},
 {"id":"39","answer":[{"option":"3","text":"LOW"}],"type":"b"},
 {"id":"40","answer":["Hello Word"],"type":"c"}]
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayok");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json = $row[0];
        if(!is_null($json)){                          

        $json = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $json);  
        $jason_array = json_decode($json,true);

    // id2 
            $id = array();
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
            if (array_key_exists('type', $data)) {  
            if (array_key_exists('answer', $data)) { 
                foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                $answers[] = isset($ans['text']) ? $ans['text'] : $ans;  
                }

            $id[] = ' ID='.$data['id'].', TYPE='.$data['type'].', AWNSER='.$answers;
            }
            }
            }
            }
            // lets check first your $types variable has value or not?
             $ids= implode(',',$id); /// implode yes if you got values
            $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql1."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this is my output:

```
update user_survey_start set id2=' ID=38, TYPE=a, AWNSER=Array,
```

and I got `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\json\awnser.php on line 29`
I want to have value of $answers

Comment: Nothing Changed. And Still I Have `update user_survey_start set id2=' ID=38, TYPE=a, AWNSER=Array,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved By Myself**
Because I Couldn't Put Awnser Directly To `id[]`, I Taked Awnser Like This:

```
$id[] = ' ID='.$data['id'].', TYPE='.$data['type'];
$id[] = isset($ans['text']) ? ' AWNSER='.$ans['text'] : ' AWNSER='.$ans;
```

And This is My Code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","arrayok");
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$sql="SELECT `survey_answers`,us_id FROM `user_survey_start`";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
        $json = $row[0];
        if(!is_null($json)){                          

        $json = preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $json);  
        $jason_array = json_decode($json,true);

    // id2 
            $id = array();
            foreach ($jason_array as $data) {
            if (array_key_exists('id', $data)) {
            if (array_key_exists('type', $data)) {    
            if (array_key_exists('answer', $data)) { 
                foreach($data['answer'] as $ans){
                $id[] = ' ID='.$data['id'].', TYPE='.$data['type'];
                $id[] = isset($ans['text']) ? ' AWNSER='.$ans['text'] : ' AWNSER='.$ans;
                }



            }
            }
            }
            }
            // lets check first your $types variable has value or not?
             $ids= implode(',',$id); /// implode yes if you got values
            $sql1="update user_survey_start set id2='$ids' where us_id=".$row[1];//run update sql
            echo $sql1."<br>";
            mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

        }
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It would be great if you could explain a bit more on how you solved your problem :)

Comment: I Updated My Awnser, Because I Couldn't Put Awnser Directly To id[] after `id` and `type`, I Taked Awnser Invidual, Like This:`$id[] = ' ID='.$data['id'].', TYPE='.$data['type'];
$id[] = isset($ans['text']) ? ' AWNSER='.$ans['text'] : ' AWNSER='.$ans;`